# Safari adds "localhost" in front of all URLs, why?

Tags: laravel, nginx, https, localhost

*First, a disclaimer: The nature of this problem forces me to publish an affiliate link (to a german fashion shop) here. This is NOT a shady attempt to trick people into using the shop behind, I just need advice in a serious URL breaking problem. The link is classic affiliate, NOT pay-by-click or so. Hope this is clear :)*

My problem: I'm using affiliate links on a project which I get directly from certain online shops. The links always work fine in all browsers, except safari.

Example link: https://partners.webmasterplan.com/click.asp?ref=839072&site=7270&type=text&tnb=74&diurl=//www.mirapodo.de/converse-essentials-winterwool-jogginghose-herren-anthrazit-8519541.html

Leads to the correct site in all browsers EXCEPT Safari mobile (iOS 11 and 12) and Safari on macOS High Sierra, which route the browser to: http://localhost//www.mirapodo.de/converse-essentials-winterwool-jogginghose-herren-anthrazit-8519541.html?ref=839072&affmt=2&affmn=74 (note the localhost in front of the URL). As this is not a valid link, Safari will cancel the request and give an internal error page.

**My suggestion:**
The tracking link contains `... url=//www.mirapodo.de/ ...` which looks suspicious. The links are hardcoded, directly by the shops, I cannot change them and didn't touched them in any way. I'm using nginx, Laravel, a domain with SSL/https, totally standard settings.

**My question:** Why is this happening, and how can I fix it ?

Comment: What happens from the neglected Safari when you browse this? (Note that https was made explicit) https://partners.webmasterplan.com/click.asp?ref=839072&site=7270&type=text&tnb=74&diurl=https://www.mirapodo.de/converse-essentials-winterwool-jogginghose-herren-anthrazit-8519541.html

Comment: That's an invalid query string... slashes should be encoded.  It's a problem on their end since they aren't properly encoding query string values.

Comment: Looks like not related to your Laravel app, but to the ASP page that redirects to it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue: **It's a bug in a frontend compression tool** named laravel-page-speed (v1.8.7) that removes redundant data, but in this case two times `https` isn't exactly redundant :)

The issue on GitHub: [link](https://github.com/renatomarinho/laravel-page-speed/issues/85)

The tool used: [laravel-page-speed](https://github.com/renatomarinho/laravel-page-speed)